# Why does my decompiled jar get so many errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiling

I have decompiled a jar (it's a pretty complex app written in an old Java version) using JD-GUI and put the java files into Eclipse along with all the required external libraries (jars). The problem is I get a lot of errors about methods not working for a specific type, errors about access$0 and many other issues.

Why is this happening? Is it impossible to decompile complex jars and open the project in Eclipse?

I get errors that the methods used are not available for some types, The method access$0(...) is undefined for the type ...

Comment: You can decompile jar. Show the error you are getting and tell how are you creating jar in your question

Comment: You likely have synthetic or obfuscated fields which haven't been transformed/rewritten into a usable code form. Some decompilers do this automatically, otherwise you need to go in by hand and fix some references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

It is happening because the decompiler is not able to figure out Java source code that will compile to equivalent bytecodes.

The task for a decompiler is difficult.  When the compiler compiles Java source code to bytecodes, a lot of information is thrown away.  It is not just the obvious stuff like comments, indentation and local variable names.  It is also the particular choices that were made about control structures.  In addition, there are various situations where the compiler has to insert *synthetic methods or fields*.

A decompiler has to do two sometimes contradictory things:

- It has to produce *readable* code.
- It has to produce code that is (hopefully) compilable and that (hopefully) means the same thing as the bytecodes.

Unfortunately, decompilers don't always get it right.  Practical decompilation is heuristic, and the heuristics are not perfect.

Obfuscators make it even harder.  Deliberately.

---

The corollary is that you should not be using decompilation and recompilation in your software development processes.

The best approach is to get hold of the original source code for the JAR you are trying to understand and modify.

Only use decompilation to help you understand other peoples' code if you have no alternative.  (For a start, it could well be a license violation.  Check to see if the software license forbids reverse engineering, etcetera.)

If you *really* need to modify bytecodes, use a bytecode disassembler ... and learn to read and edit the Java assembly language.